# Python pandas: how to run multiple univariate regression by group

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` with one column of `y` variable and many columns of `x` variables. I would like to be able to run multiple univariate regressions of `y` vs `x1`, `y` vs `x2`, ..., etc, and store the predictions back into the `DataFrame`. Also I need to do this by a group variable.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'y': np.random.randn(20),
  'x1': np.random.randn(20), 
  'x2': np.random.randn(20),
  'grp': ['a', 'b'] * 10})

def ols_res(x, y):
    return sm.OLS(y, x).fit().predict()

df.groupby('grp').apply(ols_res) # This does not work
```

The code above obviously does not work. It is not clear to me how to correctly pass the fixed `y` to the function while having `apply` iterating through the `x` columns(`x1`, `x2`, ...). I suspect there might be a very clever one-line solution to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you pass to `apply` must take a `pandas.DataFrame` as a first argument. You can pass additional keyword or positional arguments to `apply` that get passed to the applied function.  So your example would work with a small modification.  Change `ols_res` to

```
def ols_res(df, xcols,  ycol):
    return sm.OLS(df[ycol], df[xcols]).fit().predict()
```

Then, you can use `groupby` and `apply` like this

```
df.groupby('grp').apply(ols_res, xcols=['x1', 'x2'], ycol='y')
```

Or

```
df.groupby('grp').apply(ols_res, ['x1', 'x2'], 'y')
```

**EDIT**

The above code does *not* run multiple *univariate* regressions.  Instead, it runs one *multivariate* regression per group.  With (another) slight modification it will, however.

```
def ols_res(df, xcols,  ycol):
    return pd.DataFrame({xcol : sm.OLS(df[ycol], df[xcol]).fit().predict() for xcol in xcols})
```

**EDIT 2**

Although, the above solution works, I think the following is a little more pandas-y

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'y': np.random.randn(20),
  'x1': np.random.randn(20), 
  'x2': np.random.randn(20),
  'grp': ['a', 'b'] * 10})

def ols_res(x, y):
    return pd.Series(sm.OLS(y, x).fit().predict())

df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda x : x[['x1', 'x2']].apply(ols_res, y=x['y']))
```

For some reason, if I define `ols_res()` as it was originally, the resultant `DataFrame` doesn't have the group label in the index.

Comment: Actually I believe this runs one multivariate regression instead of looping through the columns and run multiple univariate regressions.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have read the question more closely. Please see my edit.